# How to do PHP to MS SQL connection?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-7, xampp

I'm using xampp and my php version is php5.5.6 in WIN-7 os. I want to connect the MS SQL Server from my PC. I'm having MSSQL SERVER in my LAN. how to do that, I'm new to PHP?

Comment: Have you read through the php.net docs? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php

Comment: Yes! i followed those steps and added the DLL files to the php.ini file and then i used the code  $link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');   and it gives a Fatal error there is no such method.

Comment: i added the dll files in to the extensions directory. then how to compile PHP with --with-mssql[=DIR].

Comment: Thanks @John McMahon. i did it by the way it said in manual....

Answer (score 0):

Right from the manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

If this code does not work, then make sure you can ping the database server from the web server.